# Iterate through Json Object to get first object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object like this:

```
{"2":[{"id":1,"index":"1.0000"},{"id":2,"index":"2.0000"}]}
```

How do I loop through the object.

I tried like this:

```
$.each(jsonObject, function (i, data)
{
   $.each(data, function (i, innerData)
   {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(innerData));
   });
});
```

This is what I get:

```
{"id":1,"index":"1.0000"}
{"id":2,"index":"2.0000"}
```

How do I get value `2` from {"**2**":[{"id":1,"index":"1.0000"},{"id":2,"index":"2.0000"}]}

Comment: which `2` are you pertaining to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get is using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**, this will retrieve object keys as an array.

```js
var jsonObject = {
  "2": [{
    "id": 1,
    "index": "1.0000"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "index": "2.0000"
  }]
};

var key = Object.keys(jsonObject)[0];

document.write(key)

$.each(jsonObject[key], function(i, innerData) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(innerData));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(jsonObject, function (i, data)
{
    console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: some explanation is usually appreciated

Comment: he asked "How do I get value 2 from {"2":[{"id":1,"index":"1.0000"},{"id":2,"index":"2.0000"}]}"

he is talking about the key "2"